# Comparação sendo repetida gradativamente em registros diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

No meu código abaixo tenho uma tabela que mostra alguns dados e um botão para editar.

Quando clico no botão editar uma vez ele funciona normalmente, abre a modal com os **`input's`** preenchidos e o ***JavaScript*** identifica se houve algo alterado para habilitar o botão de confirmar a edição.

O problema é que se eu repetir o processo noutros registros o comando de comparação vai multiplicando gradativamente, ou seja, no primeiro registro faz a comparação uma vez, no segundo duas vezes e assim sucessivamente.

Não estou conseguindo pensar numa forma de resolver este problema para que o comando de comparação seja feito só uma vez em cada registro.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue código:

```js
$('body').on("click", ".edit", function(){
  $('#confEditar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#nomeEditar').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
  $('#emailEditar').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(2).text());
  $('#nomeEditar').focus(function(){
    nome = $(this).val();
    console.log(nome + ' = ' + $(this).val());
  });
  $('#nomeEditar').focusout(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != nome) {
      $('#confEditar').removeAttr('disabled');
      console.log('Diferente: ' + $(this).val() + ' e ' + nome);
    } else {
      console.log('Igual: ' + $(this).val() + ' e ' + nome);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>carlos@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cesar</td>
      <td>cesar@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
      <td>luis@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Registro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="nomeEditar">
        <input type="text" id="emailEditar">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="confEditar" disabled>Editar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que adicionas auscultadores de eventos a cada click ao mesmo elemento com `.focus` e `.focusout` e ele vai acumulando e correndo todos.

Sugiro mudares a lógica do código para algo assim:

```js
(function($nomeEditar, $emailEditar, $confEditar) {
  var _nome, _mail;
    $($nomeEditar, $confEditar).on('input', function() {
      var mudou = _nome != $nomeEditar.val() || _mail != $emailEditar.val();
      console.log('O valor mudou?', mudou ? 'SIM' : 'NÃO');
      $('#confEditar').attr('disabled', !mudou);
    });


  $('body').on("click", ".edit", function() {
    $('#confEditar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    _nome = $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();
    _mail = $(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(2).text();
    $nomeEditar.val(_nome);
    $emailEditar.val(_mail);
  });
  
})($('#nomeEditar'), $('#emailEditar'), $('#confEditar'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>carlos@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cesar</td>
      <td>cesar@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
      <td>luis@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Registro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="nomeEditar">
        <input type="text" id="emailEditar">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="confEditar" disabled>Editar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sempre me salvando! Obrigado Sergio!